# ImageMagick - remove extra space from scanned pictures

Tags: imagemagick

I have several scanned images that look like this:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a41fC.png)

And I need to remove the extra (black) space from the right side, so the resulted image should look like this:
[cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux3yR.png)

I can do this with:`convert 1.jpg -gravity East -chop "$x"x0 2.jpg` but how can I determine the size to be removed (in this case, $x)?
[calculate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yMoJ.png)

It looks like $x should be the shortest length from the area of interest to the right margin. Also, the space to be removed seems to be always black, but not "perfectly" black.

I also tried `-trim +repage` but it didn't seem to be what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick by using -trim with a fuzz value to account for the non-uniform black.

Input:

[image]

```
convert bla.png -fuzz 15% -trim +repage bla_new.png
```

Result:

[image]

Or if you want to get rid of all the black, use -define trim:percent-background.  (It requires a relatively recent version of Imagemagick)

```
convert bla.png -fuzz 15% -background black -define trim:percent-background=0% -trim +repage bla_new2.png
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, `-fuzz` actually works. Exactly what I needed. `-define trim:percent-background` is very handy too, I can use it for a bit more aggressive crop (and more aesthetically pleasing results). Thank you very much!